# Adding new ZLayer.environment in Scala using ZIO

Tags: scala, zio

I have a ZIO program that looks something like this

```
object EUMApp extends ZIOAppDefault {

  override def run: ZIO[Any & ZIOAppArgs & Scope, Any, Any] =
    ZIO
      .service[Some.Server]
      .flatMap(_.run())
      .provideSomeLayer {
        AppConfig.live >>> AppEnvironment.live)
      }
}
```

```
  type SomeTask1  = Something1[Task]
  type SomeTask2  = Something2[Task]
  type SomeEnv = SomeTask1 & SomeTask2


  // noinspection TypeAnnotation
  val live = ZLayer.environment[SomeTask1]
    ++ ZLayer.environment[SomeTask2]
    ++ Health.SimpleService.live
    ++ Some.Server.live
    ++ Logger.live
```

However,I want to add a new ZLayer to live, say
type SomeTask3  = Something3[Task]

So I create a new type and add it using ++ ZLayer.environment[SomeTask3]. It looks like the following

```
type SomeTask1  = Something1[Task]
  type SomeTask2  = Something2[Task]
type SomeTask3  = Something3[Task]
  type SomeEnv = SomeTask1 & SomeTask2 & SomeTask3


  // noinspection TypeAnnotation
  val live = ZLayer.environment[SomeTask1]
    ++ ZLayer.environment[SomeTask2]
++ ZLayer.environment[SomeTask3]
    ++ Health.SimpleService.live
    ++ Some.Server.live
    ++ Logger.live
```

However, when I add it, I get type mismatch error:

```
found   : zio.ZLayer[zio.Scope with com.name.some.service.env.AppConfig with zio.Scope with com.name.some.service.env.AppConfig with zio.Scope with com.name.some.service.env.AppConfig with com.name.some.service.env.AppConfig with com.name.some.service.env.AppConfig with com.name.some.service.env.AppConfig with zio.Scope with com.name.some.service.env.AppConfig with com.name.core.web.email.client.EmailClient[zio.Task],Any,com.name.some.service.env.AppEnvironment.TenantCachedPool with com.name.some.service.env.AppEnvironment.CacheSvc with com.name.some.service.env.AppEnvironment.MailCli with com.name.some.service.env.AppEnvironment.PermissionClient with com.name.some.service.env.AppEnvironment.TenantClient with com.name.some.service.env.AppEnvironment.LaunchDarklyCli with com.name.core.db.AuthPool with com.name.core.web.HealthApi.Service[zio.UIO,com.name.core.web.HealthApi.SimpleResponse] with com.name.some.service.env.someWebService.Server with com.name.some.service.env.AppEnvironment.someSvc with Unit with Unit]
    (which expands to)  zio.ZLayer[zio.Scope with com.name.some.service.env.AppConfig with zio.Scope with com.name.some.service.env.AppConfig with zio.Scope with com.name.some.service.env.AppConfig with com.name.some.service.env.AppConfig with com.name.some.service.env.AppConfig with com.name.some.service.env.AppConfig with zio.Scope with com.name.some.service.env.AppConfig with com.name.core.web.email.client.EmailClient[zio.Task],Any,com.name.core.db.TenantDbPools with com.name.core.cache.Cache[zio.Task] with **com.name.core.web.email.client.EmailClient[zio.Task]** with com.name.some.service.clients.permissions.somePermissionClient[zio.Task] with com.name.some.service.clients.tenants.someTenantClient[zio.Task] with com.name.some.service.clients.launchDarkly.LaunchDarklyClient[zio.Task] with com.name.core.db.ConnPool[com.name.core.db.DbType.Auth.type,com.name.core.db.Backend.Postgres.type] with com.name.core.web.HealthApi.Service[zio.UIO,com.name.core.web.HealthApi.SimpleResponse] with com.name.some.service.env.someWebService.Server with com.name.some.service.someService[zio.Task] with Unit with Unit]
 required: zio.ZLayer[com.name.some.service.env.AppConfig with Any with zio.ZIOAppArgs with zio.Scope,Any,?]
          ) >>> (AppEnvironment.live ++ AppEnvironment.migrateLayer))
```

I can't figure out how to solve this. Where does the program detect the type? Is it in Some.Server?

It looks something like this
sealed trait Server extends SomeService[SomeEnv, AppConfig] {...}

I add the new type to SomeEnv but not it doesn't fix the issue

Comment: Could you update the question showing the full error you got? The `type SomeTask3 = Something2[Task]` is correct? could be `= Something3[Task]` instead of `2`? I understand that this is just an example and not your code, but just in case. If it is possible, please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Yes it should be type ```SomeTask3 = Something3[Task]``` edited my question

The error looks something like this

```type mismatch;
 found   : zio.ZLayer[...]
(which expands to)  zio.ZLayer[...]
 ) >>> (AppEnvironment.live)```

Comment: Could you edit your question and post the full error message there? Comments are useful to request clarification, not to detail your problem. It will be easier to help you if you can provide  a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I added the full error message, let me know if it is enough